# How do I limit the result attributes coming back from algolia?

Tags: javascript, security, algolia

When I use algolia's instantsearch, the url that I hit returns all the attributes for the object that is hit. I have multiple different types of users and I don't want to just display something like a user's email to the entire world. Is there a way to query algolia differently so that I can limit the returned resultset before it comes to the page?

My current idea is to funnel everything through the our backend but I don't like the idea of limiting the spead of my search results by my own server response speed.

Here's an example of the algolia hit that returns all of my keys:

```
https://identifier-dsn.algolia.net/1/indexes/localhost_users/query?x-algolia-agent=Algolia%20for%20vanilla%20JavaScript%203.18.0&x-algolia-application-id=identifier&x-algolia-api-key=secret_letters
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For better control over what kind of data is returned, you can configure the `attributesToRetrieve` and `attributesToHighlight` of your index. Take a look at the documentation for the `attributesToRetrieve` [here](https://www.algolia.com/doc/api-client/javascript/parameters/attributesToRetrieve/#attributestoretrieve).

**Edit:** Also, use `unretrievableAttributes` if you want don't want someone with a Search API key to get access to some attributes

Comment: Do you know if there is another way to filter that?  Technically, someone could go into the interface and alter attributesToRetrieve, that still seems like a security hole.

Comment: If you want more control, you can also use `unretrievableAttributes `, that can only be modified using the Admin key. In that way you can have the security that you need. For more info, check this [FAQ](https://www.algolia.com/doc/faq/searching/what-is-attributestoretrieve-and-unretrievableattributes/) for a comparison